Recaptcha Not Working All of a Sudden
Our live CIVICRM environment is CiviCRM 5.67.1, Joomla 4.4.8, PHP 8.1, hosted on Linode.
I have had Recaptcha v2 on our contribution forms for a couple years now and everything worked great.  Today, I received a ticket from my client saying that the Recaptcha is kicking out the error "Please go back and complete the CAPTCHA at the bottom of this form" repeatedly although the "I'm not a robot" box is checked.
Went into Google, ensuring that the API keys are valid.  I even deleted and added new keys and then making sure that the keys are entered correctly into the CiviCRM system settings.  All to no avail.
Any ideas what the issue might be all of a sudden?  Flip side, is there a way to remove recaptcha from CIVICRM? (I tried by removing the keys, unchecking the recaptcha on the profiles, etc., and the recaptcha box still shows).

This question is similar to: Public contribution pages failing! Recaptcha not working. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
